# segmentation fault with encoding program

Tags: c++, c, encoding

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    int n;
    FILE *f1;
    char fn[]={"test.txt"};
    int c;
    f1=fopen(fn,"r");
    c=fgetc(f1);
    while(c!=EOF){
        if ((c<'Z')&&(c>'A')) c=c+n;
    }
    fputc(c,f1);
    fclose(f1);

}
```

i'm trying to write a program for encoding(!? idk if that's what it's called since english is my 2nd language). if i enter the number of step as 4 it should change A to E, B to F and so on. but it keeps showing "Segmentation fault (core dumped)". idk what's wrong with it, pls help me.

Comment: use gdb. handle your errors ( with fopen ). what is it that you are trying todo. and what is n used for ( it is uninitialised )

Comment: unrelated to the segmentation fault, but your while loop will likely run forever

Comment: no i don't have any warning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found these problems in your code:

- `n` is not initialised in the program
- `r` is read only mode in order to write you must use `w+` or `r+`.
- `fputc( int c, FILE *fp );` This function can be used to write to the file. It returns the written character written on success otherwise EOF if there is an error.
- The segmentation fault is due to the `r` mode which is used in the file program try running the program using `w+` mode.